# How to compare phone numbers?

Tags: android

As PhoneNumberUtils is deprecated, How can we two phone numbers if they're identical enough for caller ID purposes. I mean different formats +44xxxxxxxxxx, 0xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: [`PhoneNumberUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html) is not deprecated, despite what your post says.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the PhoneNumberUtils.compare function doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

reverse strings and compare only first 10 characters?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be for you to create a regular expression that would parse the actual phone number xxx-xxxx from any of it's prefixes (+xx, xxx).

Comment: can you give me a code example for you answer ?? or where to search for it?